syslog-ng kafka destination error: Error parsing config, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
I am trying to set up a Kafka destination in syslog-ng, but encoutering the following error:
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: Error parsing config, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting '}' in /etc/syslo>
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 7       destination d_file {
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 8           file("/var/log/syslog-ng/test.log");
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 9       };
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 10
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 11      destination d_kafka {
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 12---->     kafka(
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 12---->     ^^^^^
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 13              topic("syslog")
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 14              bootstrap servers("172.31.0.228:9094")
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 15          );
Oct 09 17:44:20 ip-172-31-0-228 syslog-ng[241321]: 16      };

Config file:
source s_net {
    udp(port(514));
};

destination d_file {
    file("/var/log/syslog-ng/test.log");
};

destination d_kafka {
    kafka(
        topic("syslog")
        bootstrap-servers("172.31.0.228:9094")
    );
};

log {
    source(s_net);
    destination(d_file);
    destination(d_kafka);
    level(debug);
};

Kafka also present in available modules:
Available-Modules: map-value-pairs,afprog,basicfuncs,afsocket,sdjournal,kafka,rate-limit-filter,cryptofuncs,linux-kmsg-format,pacctformat,hook-commands,timestamp,pseudofile,syslogformat,affile,json-plugin,system-source,tags-parser,tfgetent,confgen,disk-buffer,afuser,cef,csvparser,kvformat,regexp-parser,appmodel
As far as I can see the everything is correct, does anyone have an idea what I am missing?

Where did you get this config from? What docs are you following? The official config is different. Also Port 9094 isn't a common Kafka port
